# Is the range of inception score flexible or bounded based on number of classes?

Tags: math, generative-model, image-generation

Inception score is used to evaluate the generative models. It is a score given based on quality and diversity of images generated.

I have doubt about the range of inception score because of the reason that [an article](https://medium.com/octavian-ai/a-simple-explanation-of-the-inception-score-372dff6a8c7a) mentions about the possibility of range $[0, \infty]$ and still talks about upper bound in practical setting

> The lowest score possible is zero. Mathematically the highest possible
> score is infinity, although in practice there will probably emerge a
> non-infinite ceiling. For a ceiling to the IS, imagine that our
> generators produce perfectly uniform marginal label distributions and
> a single label delta distribution for each image — then the score
> would be bounded by the number of labels.

Suppose I have 1000 classes/labels in my task, then is it possible to get an inception score of 2000? Or is it mandatory that the inception score [must lie](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-implement-the-inception-score-from-scratch-for-evaluating-generated-images/) in $[1, 1000]$?

To be concise: Is bounding inception score to a particular range $[1, \text{number of classes}]$ optional or mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are right. The IS is bound by the number of classes.

This paper titled "[A Note on the Inception Score](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01973.pdf)" clearly shows a formal proof of the same. Please head to section 3.3 of the main text for a description and the appendix for the proof.